# Instance Memory Address

Tags: python

When I create a class instance, if I print the instance name, I get the memory address, like the code below:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, color, model):
        self.color = color
        self.model = model

civic = Car('blue', 'civic')
print civic
```

The output is:

```
<Car object at 0x7fe4c4a1bfd0>
```

I sense that I could do a lot with this information, but I can't find information of what I can do. For what I should use this memory address? I can store this to some database just referencing the memory address?
I appreciate any information of the possibilities for this.

Comment: You don't. It's an opaque value, letting you distinguish between different instances. It *happens* to be the memory address, but that is an implementation detail.

Comment: Note, this is just the default implementation of `__str__` inherited from `__object__`. It's suppose to be generic, but you could implement your own `__str__`. Many classes do. So try `def __str__(self): return "i'm a Car string"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. It's an opaque value, letting you distinguish between different instances. It *happens* to be the memory address, but that is an implementation detail.

What you see is the hex conversion of the return value of the [`id()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> **CPython implementation detail**: This is the address of the object in memory.

Note the *implementation detail* note there.

The ID is included because just plain `<Car object>` is not nearly as helpful when you have more than one instance. You could also supply your own [`__repr__` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) to make that string a little more useful *for your application*; you could make it return a reproducible expression, for example:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'Car({self.color!r}, {self.model!r})'
```

Now the representation looks like this:

```
>>> Car('red', 'Ferrari')
Car('red', 'Ferrari')
```

which may be a little more helpful when you are debugging.

Comment: I though that I could use this for some reason. Thanks!